# If p,q,r are positive and are in A.P the roots of quadratic equations $px^2+qx+r=0$ are real for

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

The answer is $|\frac rp -7|\ge 4\sqrt 3$

Since they are in AP
$$2q=p+r$$
For x to be real 
$$q^2-4pr\ge 0$$
Then $$(\frac{p+r}{2})^2-4pr\ge 0$$
$$p^2+r^2-14pr\ge 0$$
I don’t know that to do next. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: @stevengregory which is strange, given that $14= 2\times 7$ and $7$ is part of the answer.  $p^2+r^2-14pr\ge 0$ looks good to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next divide through by $p^2$, complete the square and take square roots:

$$p^2+r^2-14pr\ge 0$$
$$\left(\frac rp\right)^2 - 14 \frac rp \ge -1$$
$$\left(\frac rp\right)^2 - 14 \frac rp +49 \ge 48$$
$$\left(\frac rp-7\right)^2 \ge 48$$
$$\left|\frac rp-7\right| \ge \sqrt{48}$$
$$\left|\frac rp-7\right| \ge 4\sqrt{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Divide both sides of the equation by $p^2$ to produce a polynomial in $\frac{r}{p}$ and then complete the square.